# Getting text from array to UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

I am new at Swift coding and i need help.

I am having a big problem getting text from a UITableViewCell to another viewcontroller.

I have created an array but it dont seem to copy into the UITableViewCell?

this is my code

import UIKit

var container = likedViewController()

class likedViewController: UIInputViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, icebreakerData {
    func textChoice(string: String?) {
    }

```
var likedList: [String] = ["Hello there"]

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return likedList.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel!.text = likedList[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(likedList[row])

    }


//-----------------

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
             heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     // Make the first row larger to accommodate a custom cell.
        return 80
     }



@IBAction func ad(_ sender: Any) {
    container = likedViewController()
    container.likedList.append("I am another one")
        print("I am working")
}


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
func hey (){
    let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KeyboardViewController") as? KeyboardViewController
    selectionVC?.iceBreakerDataDelegate = self
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

In your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, you can then create the new VC and push it to your UINavigationController.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row
    self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(likedList[row])

    // if this is your destination VC
    let selectionVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "KeyboardViewController") as? KeyboardViewController

    // hand over the data
    selectionVC?.iceBreakerDataDelegate = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(selectionVC, animated: true)

    }
```

In case you are not using a `NavigationController`, you can simply present viewcontroller. 
`self.present(selectionVC, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Comment: Thank you for a fast reply. I get this message now.

Comment: @ManasK you have 3 errors. 1. You are trying to call insertText on icebreaker object, but it doesn't have that function. Are you sure that object has that function? 2. Second is with the incorrect assigning of the delegates. You need to check the type again. 3. You have an extra `.` in the function. It should be `navigationController?.pushViewController(selectionVC, animated: true)`